# Unable to Extract Rich Text ---DOC, DOCX

Tags: python, ms-word, richtextbox, python-docx

**Problem:**

- https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx only extracts plain text

**I need:**

- A Python module for extracting rich text from doc/docx files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you feel brave and have time you can use uno & OpenOffice for that job http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_bridge I have used it from c#.